# Moving One Flutter Slider Updates All Sliders Simultaneously

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make a few sliders for audio functionality. I've created a function that creates and updates a slider after input. The problem I'm having is that when I have declared the function multiple times, it updates all of the slider values at the same time.

How would I go about ensuring that the slider only returns a value that is specific to that single slider?

Below is the code:

```
Material SliderWidget(Alignment alignment, Color sliderColor, int totalDivisions) {
    double koalaValue;
    return Material(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Slider(
          value: sliderValue,
          min: 0.0,
          max: 9.0,
          divisions: totalDivisions,
          activeColor: sliderColor,
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              sliderValue = newValue;
              if (sliderValue >= 0.0 && sliderValue <= 3.5) {
                print("We're in resolve!");
              }
              if (sliderValue >= 4.0 && sliderValue <= 5.5) {
                print('Normal music state set');
              }
              if (sliderValue >= 4.6 && sliderValue <= 9.0) {
                print("Tension is rising!");
              }
            })
          },
          inactiveColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: set state causes the widget to rebuild. This causes you functions that build the sliders to be invoked every time on rebuild. So instead of using a function and return a slider, create a separate widget that builds your slider

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks so much for the explanation @VamsiKrishna that helps a lot.